# Can I compute the p-value for a list of incidence rates?

Tags: p-value, scipy, incidence-rate-ratio

Coming back to statistics after a long time, so please forgive any ignorance.

I'm curious how I might be able to argue for statistical significance of a test.  Specifically, I'm after a `p-value` for my test.

I ran a test along with a control with approximately the same, reasonably large group size.  For example:

```
Group A (control) = list of incidence rates in units of (seizures / (rat * yr))
                  = [0.01, 0.014, ... 0.012]

Group B (test)    = list of incidence rates in units of (seizures / (rat * yr))
                  = [0.012, 0.01, ... 0.011]
```

I want to know whether my test shows a statistically significantly difference - whether the frequency of the event was meaningfully reduced.

It appears that this magic calculator does exactly this.  How can I do this in python?

[image]

http://www.cdc.gov/nhsn/PS-Analysis-resources/PDF/StatsCalc.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can obtain a p-value, but it will take some effort to assure the model you pick models your data well.

Your data are most likely a count of seizures over some measure of time. If your time of observation is the same for each experimental unit (rat), consider using a Poisson regression. The dependent variable is the number of seizures for each rat and the independent variable is Group (A/B).

You may also consider negative binomial regression if the Poisson model does not fit well.

Comment: yes the duration and start of observation is exactly the same between the groups

Comment: can you elaborate more on the Poisson regression and how that can lead me to a p-value using scipy?  http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Poisson.fit.html, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html

Comment: is there any additional help you can provide?

Comment: This seems like the most standard case of Poisson regression, if you have the counts (rather than rates). The rates alone are (almost) meaningless (0.01 could be 1 event per 100 time units or 1000 events per 100,000 time units and the amount of information contained in the two is enormous).